# Angular filtering problem when using pipe and map response

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

shop.service.ts code

```
getProducts(brandId?: number, typeId?: number) {
let params = new HttpParams();

if (brandId){
  params = params.append('brandId', brandId.toString());
}

if (typeId){
  params = params.append('typeId', typeId.toString());
}

return this.http.get<IPagination>(this.baseUrl + 'products', {observe: 'response', params})
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      return response.body;
    })
  );
```

}

and shop.component.ts code here

```
getProducts(){
this.shopService.getProducts(this.brandIdSelected, this.typeIdSelected).subscribe(response => {
  this.products = response.data;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

Please see those code and give me a suggestion Why response.data is showing error in shop.component.ts?
Note: Object is possiblly 'null' : ts(2531) error message showing.

Comment: Firstly, Don't add code images instead paste the code which is throwing an error. and it seems your API is not returning the data. Can you check that in network, or just log that to console? Also, It seems you are returning response.body(it seems null) ?

Comment: Please, be so kind and post no images but the real code here. I won't type all your code myself just to be able to show you where your problem is located.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable advice. All data are showing correctly but the error has been occurred.

Comment: I have updated my post now please help me

Comment: I can't see on which line the error is thrown. Can you provide the `console` screenshot

Comment: this.products = response.data; Console is ok and all data is showing correctly but this line is showing error

Comment: This suggests you have `strict` mode enabled in your project. you are getting an error because your service has an undefined returned time. and `response.data` is making the assumption that there will always be a response. you can use `response?.data` as one option. but you should probably do better type definitions on your service methods. in themean time, I'd suggest  reading up on typescript script mode here https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `http.get()` might return no value.

```
this.http.get<IPagination>(this.baseUrl + 'products', {observe: 'response', params}).pipe(map(response => {
        // response can be null or undefined and so can response.body
        return response.body;
    })
);
```

But here you do not take this possibility into account and directly try to access `response.data`.

```
getProducts(){
    this.shopService.getProducts(this.brandIdSelected, this.typeIdSelected).subscribe(response => {
      this.products = response.data;
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Do it with an if-condition. Then the compiler won't throw this error.

```
getProducts(){
    this.shopService.getProducts(this.brandIdSelected, this.typeIdSelected).subscribe(response => {
        // only if response is not null or undefined, access the data-field
        if (response) {
            this.products = response.data;
        }

}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Wow. It works fine. Many many thanks for your kind response.

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution. Many thanks in advance!